# Query based on a given raw data table structure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Planning to use a table for storing all trip points for every trips,  how to get required output based on below table data using SQL Server T-SQL statement or I need to re-define the table structure?

Raw data in `[trip-points]` table:

| Trip Type | Trip Name | Trip Loc seq | Trip Point No | Trip Point Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRAVEL | N-ASIA | 1 | 0001 | HK |
| TRAVEL | N-ASIA | 2 | 0002 | Japan |
| TRAVEL | N-ASIA | 3 | 0003 | South Korea |
| TRAVEL | S-ASIA | 1 | 0004 | Thailand |
| TRAVEL | S-ASIA | 2 | 0005 | Singapore |
| BUSINESS | N-ASIA | 1 | 0001 | HK |
| BUSINESS | N-ASIA | 2 | 0006 | TAIWAN |

Expected result:

| Trip Type | Trip Name | Trip Point 01 | Trip Point 02 | Trip Point 03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRAVEL | N-ASIA | 0001-HK | 0002-Japan | 0003-South Korea |
| TRAVEL | S-ASIA | 0004-Thailand | 0005-Singapore |  |
| BUSINESS | N-ASIA | 0001-HK | 0006-TAIWAN |  |

Comment: You usually do that sort of data formatting in your client side application, not the database

Comment: The output you want isn't table data, it's a custom report. In languages like Python or applications like Excel this is produced by *transposing*, converting rows into columns. You can't do that in SQL, the language. SQL requires structured data. That means the columns must *always* be known. You can't have an arbitrary number of columns. The PIVOT command can turn rows into columns but even then, the columns must be know in advance.

Comment: How are you going to use that output? You may be able to generate JSON output with a similar shape eg `[{'TripType':'TRAVEL', 'TripName':'ASIA', TripPoints: ['001-HK','002-Japan',...]}`. Or even include the trip point details as actual objects

Answer (score 1):

We can use a pivot query approach here.  Assuming there would only be a maxmimum of 3 trip points:

```sql
SELECT
    [Trip Type],
    [Trip Name],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Trip Loc seq] = 1
             THEN [Trip Point No] + '-' + [Trip Point Name] END) AS [Trip Point 01],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Trip Loc seq] = 2
             THEN [Trip Point No] + '-' + [Trip Point Name] END) AS [Trip Point 02],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [Trip Loc seq] = 3
             THEN [Trip Point No] + '-' + [Trip Point Name] END) AS [Trip Point 03]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    [Trip Type],
    [Trip Name];
```

Comment: You need to know the number of trips in advance

Comment: My answer assumes only 3 trips.  For a variable number, we would need some kind of dynamic SQL approach.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is *always* a maximum (you can't have a million columns anyway) so you may as well just write out the maximum possible in the table.

Answer (score 0):

data

```
CREATE TABLE TripPoints(
   Trip_Type       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,Trip_Name       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,Trip_Loc_seq    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Trip_Point_No   VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL
  ,Trip_Point_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO TripPoints
(Trip_Type,Trip_Name,Trip_Loc_seq,Trip_Point_No,Trip_Point_Name) VALUES 
('TRAVEL','N-ASIA',1,'0001','HK'),
('TRAVEL','N-ASIA',2,'0002','Japan'),
('TRAVEL','N-ASIA',3,'0003','South Korea'),
('TRAVEL','S-ASIA',1,'0004','Thailand'),
('TRAVEL','S-ASIA',2,'0005','Singapore'),
('BUSINESS','N-ASIA',1,'0001','HK'),
('BUSINESS','N-ASIA',2,'0006','TAIWAN');
```

use `pivot` and `concat` as follows

```
select *
from (
    select 
        Trip_Type,
        Trip_Name,
        concat('Trip Point 0',Trip_Loc_seq) name,
        concat(Trip_Point_No ,' ',Trip_Point_Name) value
    from TripPoints
) src
pivot (
  max(value)
  for name in ([Trip Point 01], [Trip Point 02], [Trip Point 03])
) piv;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qMG0QuW7)

Comment: That's the same as Tim's answer (but more complex) and requires knowing the number of trips in advance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In addition, `PIVOT` may have performance problems as compared with my version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare a dynamic query based on the MAX of Trip_Loc_seq.

**Data Preperation:**

```
CREATE TABLE TripPoints(
   Trip_Type       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  ,Trip_Name       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  ,Trip_Loc_seq    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Trip_Point_No   VARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL
  ,Trip_Point_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO TripPoints
(Trip_Type,Trip_Name,Trip_Loc_seq,Trip_Point_No,Trip_Point_Name) VALUES 
('TRAVEL','N-ASIA',1,'0001','HK'),
('TRAVEL','N-ASIA',2,'0002','Japan'),
('TRAVEL','N-ASIA',3,'0003','South Korea'),
('TRAVEL','S-ASIA',1,'0004','Thailand'),
('TRAVEL','S-ASIA',2,'0005','Singapore'),
('BUSINESS','N-ASIA',1,'0001','HK'),
('BUSINESS','N-ASIA',2,'0006','TAIWAN');
```

**Dynamic SQL Query:**

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Determine the maximum Trip_Loc_seq value
DECLARE @MaxTripLocSeq INT;
SELECT @MaxTripLocSeq = MAX(Trip_Loc_seq)
FROM TripPoints;

-- Generate a comma-separated list of column names
SET @Columns = '';
DECLARE @Counter INT = 1;
WHILE @Counter <= @MaxTripLocSeq
BEGIN
    SET @Columns = @Columns + ', MAX(CASE WHEN Trip_Loc_seq = ' + CAST(@Counter AS NVARCHAR(10)) +
                   ' THEN Trip_Point_No+''-''+Trip_Point_Name END) AS Trip_Point_No_' + CAST(@Counter AS NVARCHAR(10));
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END;
SET @Columns = RIGHT(@Columns, LEN(@Columns) - 2);

-- Prepare the dynamic SQL query
SET @DynamicSQL = '
SELECT Trip_Type, Trip_Name, ' + @Columns + '
FROM TripPoints
GROUP BY Trip_Type, Trip_Name;';
print(@DynamicSQL)
-- Execute the dynamic SQL query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL;
```